# Compare a String to a Key in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects

How do I compare a string to a JavaScript object's key? For example, here is a string and a JavaScript object. I want to compare the string (in this case, the value of myString is "Item1") to a key in this JavaScript object (in this case, the keys are Item1 and Item2):

```
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = 
{
    Item1:
    {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2:
    {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};
```

If I create a 'for' loop and run the contents of object through the loop, I want to compare the keys in this object to a string.

```
for (var x = 0; x < Object.keys(jsObject).length; x++)
{
    if (myString == /* What do I put here to compare to grab Item1 or Item2? */)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Object.keys(jsObject).x may help

Comment: sorry `Object.keys(jsObject)[x]` i dont know why we cannot do `.` here

Comment: You shouldn't use a loop for this at all. A JavaScript object gives you direct access to each of its properties by name. You don't have to loop through them comparing names to do this, simply reference the property directly. This is easier and faster too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = 
{
    Item1:
    {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2:
    {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

var keys = Object.keys(jsObject); //get keys from object as an array

keys.forEach(function(key) { //loop through keys array
  console.log(key, key == myString)
});
```

You could use a for loop, but you'd have to store the array of keys somewhere.

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = 
{
    Item1:
    {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2:
    {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

var keys = Object.keys(jsObject);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (myString == keys[i])
    console.log('match: ', keys[i])
}
```

Optionally, you can use `for..in` to get the keys as well.

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = 
{
    Item1:
    {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2:
    {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

for (var key in jsObject) {
  console.log(key, key == myString)  
}
```

Comment: This worked! I knew there was a way, but I'm not as skilled as you in JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: hi that is great, thanks , and after i get key and get pair how i should return object which is match :)

Answer (score 22):

You don't need a loop for this and shouldn't use one. Instead, reference the object property directly. This is simpler and faster:

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = {
    Item1: {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2: {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

var item;
if( jsObject.hasOwnProperty(myString) ) {
    item = jsObject[myString];
    console.log( item );
}
```

Also, I have a stylistic recommendation if you don't mind. You may note that in the code snippet above I moved the open curly braces to the end of the line above instead of a line of their own.

In most "curly brace" languages, this is merely a coding style choice that doesn't affect how the code is compiled and run. However, because of JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion, putting the open brace on its own line can break your code. Here's an example:

```js
function good() {
    return {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}

console.log( 'good:', good() );

function bad()
{
    return
    {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}

console.log( 'bad:', bad() );
```

The `good()` and `bad()` functions look like they should return the same result, the `{ foo: 'bar' }` object. That's because automatic semicolon insertion changes the `bad()` function to this:

```
function bad()
{
    return;  // <-- semicolon added, so it returns undefined, not the object
    {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}
```

Because of this I recommend the "open brace at the end of the line" style for all JavaScript code.

Answer (score 5):

### Directly test that the string is a property using `.hasOwnProperty()`

A better way is to test directly that the string is a property on the Object with [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).  The `.hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating if the object has the string as a direct property of the object. I does not indicate true if the property exists on the objects prototype.  This is equivalent to testing that the string is an entry in [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as that method returns only the objects own properties, which are enumerable. If you are concerned about the property being enumerable, then you can also use [`Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) to test that the property is also enumerable.

Using this will be faster than creating the array of keys with `Object.keys()` and searching that array.

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = {
    Item1: {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2: {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

if(jsObject.hasOwnProperty(myString)) {
    //myString is a key on the Object, but not its prototype.
    console.log(myString + ' is a property of jsObject');
}
```

### If really want to search the `keys()`, use `.indexOf()`

For the way that you are doing this, the method [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) would be more appropriate. The `.indexOf()` method searches through an array and returns the index of the first matching entry.  You can test to see that the return value is > -1 as an indicator that there is a matching entry in the array.

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = {
    Item1: {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2: {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};

if(Object.keys(jsObject).indexOf(myString)>-1) {
    //myString is a property.
    console.log(myString + ' is a property of jsObject');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a couple of ways:

```
for (var key in jsObject) {
  if (myString == key) {
  }
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(jsObject).forEach(function(key) { //loop through keys array
  if (myString == key) {
  }
});
```

or

```
for (var x = 0; x < Object.keys(jsObject).length; x++)
{
  if (myString == Object.keys(jsObject)[x])
  {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Given the use of the original object, you could simply skip the loop ...

```
if (typeof jsObject[myString] !== "undefined") {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myString = "Item1";

var jsObject = 
{
    Item1:
    {
        "apples": "red",
        "oranges": "orange",
    },
    Item2:
    {
        "bananas": "yellow",
        "pears": "green"
    }
};
for (var x = 0; x < Object.keys(jsObject).length; x++)
{
    if (myString ==(Object.keys(jsObject)[x]) )
    {
       console.log(Object.keys(jsObject)[x]+" is in object");
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ES2020 universe, and echoing some of what was said:

The way the question was posted, because object keys are unique, the string can only ever match once. Thus, no need for looping.

To 'look ahead' before referencing the value (a "maybe value", if you will), there are two pithy ways I can think of thus far not mentioned.

In the situation where you *know something* about both the string value and the object to avoid the pitfalls of the prototype, the `in` operator nicely conveys the code's intent.

```js
// perform some side-effect
if (myString in jsObject) { /* do stuff to the world */ }
```

Finally, ES2020's optional chaining combined with the nullish coalescing operators work well together to change the "type" of the return value `maybe value -> value`:

```js
// only requires jsObject be defined (which is the case here)
return jsObject?.[myString] ?? defaultValue;
```

- E

Answer (score 0):

We can easly compare and find the object what we are looking for using following

**steps:**

1. Get Object keys array using `Object.keys()` method
2. Compare Object keys and with string using `Array.find()` method
3. After got the key, we can refer the object to receive the value

**Example:**

```js
const string = 'en'
const shortDatePatterns = {
    'af-ZA': 'yyyy/MM/dd',
    'am-ET': 'd/M/yyyy',
    'ar-EN': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-BH': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-DZ': 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    'ar-EG': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-IQ': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-JO': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-KW': 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'ar-LB': 'dd/MM/yyyy'
}
const comparedString = shortDatePatterns[Object.keys(shortDatePatterns).find(key => key.includes(string.toUpperCase())?shortDatePatterns[key]:'')]

console.log(comparedString)
```